# Estilo não carregado em servidor em aplicação node.js

Tags: html, css, node.js, scss

estou com uma questão.
Estou utilizando o *github* pages para desenvolver um site utilizando o *node.js*. Em meu *host*, os estilos carregam e eu os consigo visualizar normalmente no navegador.

No entanto, quando eu tento ver a aplicação ao 'live', após o *deploy*, eu percebo que os estilos não carregam.

Segue aqui códigos importantes:

**webpack.config.js**

```
 module.exports = [{
  entry: './app.scss',
  output: {
    // This is necessary for webpack to compile
    // But we never use style-bundle.js
    filename: 'style-bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'bundle.css',
            },
          },
          { loader: 'extract-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}];
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.scss**

```
body {
  color: blue;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Aqui meu repositório se precisarem acessar outros arquivos:  https://github.com/vnsqz/vnsqz.github.io

Link do 'live': https://vnsqz.github.io

Eu vejo que tem o *app.scss* e o *bundle.css* e eu acabo ficando meio confuso em como o fluxo funciona. talvez eu devesse adicionar algum componente que transforma o *scss* em *css*, ou apenas escutando-o?